# Distinguish data received via POST and GET in Cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

The variable `cherrypy.request.params` as it is described in the API contains the query string and the POST variables in a dictionary. However combing over this, it seems that it contains every variable received after processing the full request URI to pull the GET data. This then becomes indistinguishable from POST data in the dictionary.
There seems to be no way to tell the difference, or perhaps I am wrong.

Can someone please enlighten me as to how to use purely posted data and ignore any data in the query string beyond the request URI. And yes I am aware I can find out whether it was a POST or GET request but this does not stop forgery in requests to URIs containing GET data in a POST request.

```
>http://localhost:8080/testURL/part2?test=1
>POST username = test

"cherrypy.request.params" has 2 variables
test = 1
username=test
```

Comment: There is absolutely no risk as long as you check that a request is using POST. If a malicious application can modify the query string/url of the form, it cna also easily inject inputs to get data POSTed. However, even requiring POST is not enough to secure your application against CSRF - a malicious site could simply create a hidden form that is submitted to a hidden iframe via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs aren't very clear on this point, but starting in CherryPy 3.2, you can reference `request.body.params` to obtain just the POST/PUT params. In 3.2 and below, try `request.body_params`. See http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/_cprequest.html#cherrypy._cprequest.Request.body_params